# Spreading array of objects to the list of arguments

Tags: java, arrays

I want to spread my array of *Objects* like this:

```
int size  = 3;   /* sample size */
Object[] arrayOfObjects = new Object[size];
/* initialize this array by Objects */
```

and by using some magical method, get this on output:

```
Object obj1, Object obj2, Object obj3
```

I need this kind of output, because I need to use method which allows list of arguments.

PS. My API provides **addAll** method, type of argument is: `Iterable <Some_Type>` which I don't really understand.

Comment: Use the `addAll(Iterable<>)` method. There is nothing to understand beyond realizing that every Java collection implemnts it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addAll is a method that "iterates" over the collection and adds all elements to another datastructure.

Iterable, for you this would be Iterable, creates a datastructure called an iterator that allows you to iterate over the datastructure yourself.

```
Object[] arrayOfObjects = new Object[size];
Collection<Object> myNewCollection = new ArrayList<Object>();
// use the addAll
myNewCollection.addAll(arrayOfObjects);

// use an iterator
Iterator<Object> iter = myNewCollection.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    Object object = iter.next();
    // do something with the object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
yourDataStructure.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrayOfObjects));
```

this makes use of the `addAll()` method with a `Iterable<Some_Type>` you mentioned in your question.